# Using two tensorflow models where one is for inference and another is for training

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm trying to combine two models in one graph because I need one model's inference result to modify the loss function of the other model. I wrote the code and it runs without errors but I'm not sure whether I wrote it correctly so I'm writing this thread.

In the code, I loaded two graphs like this

```
with tf.variable_scope("modelA"):
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('modelA-1000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

with tf.variable_scope("modelB"):
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('modelB-1000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

and I used modelA's result to modify modelB's loss funcion as follows

```
output_A = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("modelA_output:0")
output_B = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("modelB_output:0")
loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(output_A * tf.log(output_B ), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

Then for training, I included only modelB variables to train since I want to make Model A for inference only.

```
model_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
var_B = [var for var in model_vars if 'modelB' in var.name]
gradient = tf.gradients(loss,var_B)
trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_step = trainer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient ,var_B))

... declare session and prepare batch for training ...

for i in range(10000):
    loss_ = train_step.run(loss, feed_dict={x: batch[0]})
```

I ran it and the code runs but the loss does not decrease. What did I do wrong? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this code runs. `train_step` is an `Operation`. `Operation.run()` method takes the `feed_dict` and an optional `session`. I don't know how `train_step.run(loss, feed_dict={x: batch[0]})` can run. Generally, you would do something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   _, _loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict=...)
```

As a side note, if you have the code that produced the modelA and modelB in the first place. It is better (i.e. less brittle) to rerun that code to recreate the graph. Once the graph is created, you can restore the variable values from your checkpoint using `Saver`. This avoids doing brittle extractions like

```
output_A = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("modelA_output:0")
```